# Changing an Image on in time interval using react

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, setinterval

I am trying to change the image displayed every 1 second the first image appears then switches to the alt display and does not continue switching the pictures

```
export default class Slideshow extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getImageId = this.getImageId.bind(this);
        this.switchImage = this.switchImage.bind(this);
        this.init = this.init.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            currentImage: 0,
            image: 0

        };
    }

    getImageId() {
        if(this.currentImage < 3) {
            this.setState({
                currentImage: this.state.currentImage +1
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                currentImage: 0
            })
        }
        return this.currentImage;
    }

    switchImage() {
            this.setState({
                image: this.getImageId()
            });
    }

    init() {
        setInterval(this.switchImage, 1000)
    }


    render() {
        const imagePath = [guy, girl, wash, swifer];
        this.init();

        return (
            <div className="slideshow-container">
                <img src={imagePath[this.state.image]} alt="cleaning images"/>      
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Pictures will switch every 1 seconds to the next picture in the array and go back to original after going through whole array

Comment: Hi Justin, I just provided you a solution below, that should give you enough insight on how to integrate this feature. Let me know if you have any questions, and please consider upvoting and marking it as the answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this instead: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-sara-q3m16

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.switchImage = this.switchImage.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      currentImage: 0,
      images: [
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80",
        "https://img.purch.com/w/660/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5saXZlc2NpZW5jZS5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL2kvMDAwLzEwNC84MzAvb3JpZ2luYWwvc2h1dHRlcnN0b2NrXzExMTA1NzIxNTkuanBn",
        "https://d17fnq9dkz9hgj.cloudfront.net/uploads/2012/11/152964589-welcome-home-new-cat-632x475.jpg",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jpsGLsaZKS0/maxresdefault.jpg"
      ]
    };
  }

  switchImage() {
    if (this.state.currentImage < this.state.images.length - 1) {
      this.setState({
        currentImage: this.state.currentImage + 1
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        currentImage: 0
      });
    }
    return this.currentImage;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.switchImage, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="slideshow-container">
        <img
          src={this.state.images[this.state.currentImage]}
          alt="cleaning images"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

We can simplify your code by doing a couple of things:

1. Put the images-array in the state, so that we can iterate over
   the image-paths and keep track of the current images index.
2. So now we can consolidate `switchImage` and `getImageId` into a
   single function that serves the same purpose. We just check the
   currentImage (index) against the length of the array.
3. React also has a life-cycle method called `componentDidMount()`
   which executes logic right after a component is rendered the
   first-time. I used this to replace the `init()` function. There is an issue with calling `init()` in `render()`. Every time a component re-renders, it executes the logic in `render()`, which means you would be creating a new `setInterval()` on every subsequent re-render. `componentDidMount()` only triggers a single time, making it perfect for defining intervals.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that you called init function with in render function, whenever state get update render executes as well, so init function call again and again each time render function execute

**the solution is to set intervals in componentDidMount function**

componentDidMount run only one time after component mount in the DOM, for help related to react life cycle function do visit the official documentation

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

also have a look this post image

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html